# Customize style sheet in Safari for a specific website

Tags: css, safari, customization

I am trying to change the font-family in `live.com`, but with the methods I tried, it changes the font on every website I visit.

```
a,body, button, div, form, html, img, label, span, textarea
{
font-family: ...
}
```

I tried to write before the code the following:

```
:root[location*="live.com" {
```

or

```
@document domain("live.com") {
```

or

```
@document url-prefix("https://outlook.live.com") {
```

Then closed them with a curly bracket `}` after the initial code.
E.g:

```
@document domain("live.com") {
 a, body, button, div, form, html, img, label, span, textarea
 {
font-family: "DejaVu Sans Mono", Menlo, "Red Hat Mono", "PT Mono", "Lucida Console", "Miriam Fixed", "Miriam Mono CLM", monospace;
 }
}
```

The code did not work. What to do? I have been searching the internet for 3 hours and I can't seem to find an answer. I just need to change the font in one specific domain, `live.com`.

Comment: CSS only applies to the website that the CSS file lives on; you cannot change the look of a *different* website through CSS - you would need to make use of a browser plugin to do that.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Maybe they're talking about the _Style sheet_ setting under _Advanced_?